# Ionic android side run issue

Tags: java, ionic-framework, java-8, ionic3

I am creating application in IONIC framework. I have done with all the basic installations and able to launch the application in browser using **ionic serve** command.

Now, I want to run the application in Real Android Device. I used following command to execute the same.

**ionic cordova run android --device**

Among the most of the issues I faced, I stuck at following error, which I could not able to tackle out.

**CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater**

I have centos 7.
I have installed JDK 1.8 in the system and set its path **/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161** to both **JAVA_HOME** and **PATH**.

Can any one help me.

Thank You

Comment: Which OS you are used ?

Comment: my Operating System is CentOS 7 and I am using IONIC 3